# Wrong Tukey-letter ordering in R multcompView package

Tags: r, tukey, multcompview

I do not understand letter ordering in the function multcompletters from multcompView. According to documentation it should be according to mean of the group. In the following example, the middle group got c (from abc) and should have got b. Is this a bug?

```
require(multcompView)
# Data 
datacol <- c(21.1,20.2,21.8,20.9,23.3,21.1,20.2,21.8,20.9,23.3,19.8,16.4,
16.9,16.0,17.6,17.5,16.9,13.3,18.0,17.6,13.5,12.2,15.2,15.1,15.2,14.0)

# Group 
faccol <- c(rep(c(1,2),each=10),rep(3,6))

# Combined Dataframe 
tukeyset <- data.frame(datacol,as.factor(faccol))
colnames(tukeyset)[2] <- "faccol"

# Tukeytest 
tukeyres <- TukeyHSD(x=aov(lm(datacol~faccol,data=tukeyset)))
Tlevels <- tukeyres$faccol[,4]
multcompLetters(Tlevels) # WRONG ORDER, even reversed 
# Boxplot 
boxplot(tukeyset$datacol~tukeyset$faccol)
# adding the labels 
text(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(aggregate(data=tukeyset,datacol~faccol,mean)$datacol),
     labels=as.character(multcompLetters(Tlevels,reversed=TRUE)$Letters)[order(names(multcompLetters(Tlevels,reversed=TRUE)['Letters']$Letters))])
```

Comment: `buchst` needs to be defined to make this example reproducible. And `datacol` and `faccol` have different lengths. Regardless, I don't think `multcompLetters` is supposed to return ordered levels. See the help file for the companion functions which do order the output, e.g.`multcompLetters2(datacol ~ faccol, Tlevels, data = tukeyset)`

Comment: Thanks, I adapted the example. Also, thanks, multcompLetters2 seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Oh no just encountered this problem!  Spent 2 hours finally sorting it out!

You cannot call multcompLetters.  It will give you the completely wrong order.

You have to use multcompLetters2, multcompLetters3 or multcompLetters4.

Another very important point is you have to **convert your input dataset into a dataframe, but not tibble!**  Tibble doesn't work for this.